# Keeping track of best algorithms

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

Is there a site that keeps track of the "current best algorithms", e.g., for certain combinatorial optimization problems?

In the latter there exists a range of classic problems such as MIN st-CUT or MAX FLOW, for which the best algorithms seem to be somewhat hidden in the literature.

Comment: Wikipedia, to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

"Best algorithm" is a fuzzy term. The algorithm which is best for some particular case can very well be absolutely worst for another, similar problem. Problems differ in details (and not-so-details), in size, in available resources, sometimes an exact solution is essential, other times a rough approximation is good enough. And there are literally thousands of algorithms, with new ones added each day.

Comment: Most certainly. But I believe there are plenty of problems for which there in fact is a very clear "progress bar". Matrix multiplication is one such example. For the examples mentioned in the original question, a clearly defined setting would be "sequential algorithms for epsilon-approximation".

Comment: @smapers "Matrix multiplication is one such example." Is it? You can measure progress on $\omega$ (in $O(n^\omega)$), but many improvements on that front have too large constants in front of the polynomial to be practical. This is why [Beniamini and Schwartz](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3323188) argue to also look at the leading coefficient. So, which algorithm is better? One with a larger leading coefficient and smaller exponent or vice versa? I'd say this will depend on $n$, i.e. on you input instance.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have posted my question on the "theoretical CS" site ;)

Comment: For most problems, there in fact isn't a very clear "progress bar". The easy solutions have been found. What remains is often very specific, and "bestness" subjective.